# Big O notation - Question about definition

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I have a seemingly easy question, but I want to make sure I understand the concept well enough.

Per definition, we say that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and $C>0$ such that for all $x\in(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ one has that $|f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|$. My question is: can $\varepsilon$ and $C$ depend on $x_0$?

If yes, then it would follow that, e.g. $x^2=O(x)$ as $x\to x_0$ for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, since one could choose (if I haven't made a mistake in my computations) $\varepsilon=1/4 |x_0|$ (or less) and $C=2|x_0|$. This seems, however, a bit counterintuitive to me.

Comment: Big O notation is not a limit as $x$ approaches a value. It is an upper limit as $x$ goes towards infinity. Instead of $x\in (x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$ it is $x\gt x_0$ for some $x_0$.

Comment: People are confusing the notation. They're using $\infty$ for the centre and $x_0$ for the size of the neighbourhood, but the OP is using $x_0$ for the centre and $\varepsilon$ for the size of the neighbourhood.

Comment: I mean, even if you want to take $x\to\infty$, please use a different variable name, e.g. $x>N$ instead of $x>x_0$.

Comment: I have to add here the same comment as I did for the answer below, namely: You did not understand my question. I did not mean the asymptotics as $x\to\infty$. I meant the asymptotics as $x$ gets very near to another real value, which I denoted $x_0$. This definition appears even on Wikipedia, so I am a little  confused about the misunderstanding.

Comment: The definition everyone else is working off of is the accepted definition of big O. Are you sure about your terminology?

Comment: Check Wikipedia, under Formal definition, the sentence starting with "In many contexts..." : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Irene - If you're responding to one user in particular, use their name; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in every respect. For any $x_0$ one defines the statement  $ g= O(f)$ as $x\to x_0$  to mean that for that choice of $x_0$ there exists constants $C$ and $\epsilon>0$  (which may depend on $x_0$) such that $ |g(x)\leq C |f(x)|$. In other words $|g/f|$ is bounded (by $C$) on some  punctured interval centered at $x_0$ (of size $\epsilon$).

Some of the confusion raised in the comments arises because in many applications one wishes to discuss instead the case where $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I got that this is why people seem confused, but it seems difficult for the majority to look at different asymptotics. So, do you agree with my statement that by this definition, the constant and length of the interval may depend on $x_0$?

Comment: Yes they definitely may depend on $x_0$.

Answer (score -1):

The big O notation can be interpreted in the way that if $f(x) = O(g(x))$, then f(x) grows at most as fast as g(x). However, if we consider the definition of big O in predicate logic as given by

$\exists C>0 \exists x_0 > 0  \forall x > x_0: |f(x)| \leq C\cdot |g(x)|$,

it is clear that $C$ can’t depend on $x_0$, for its existence is not given at the time of definition of $C$. When using the definition for metric spaces, it can depend neither on $C$ nor on $x_0$. The point is that the definition for big O notation you refer to is not the one generally used where we say that the condition holds for $\forall x > x_0$ and not for $x \in B_{\epsilon} (x_0)$. In that case though your claim is indeed correct.

Comment: You did not understand my question. I did not mean the asymptotics as $x\to\infty$. I meant the asymptotics as $x$ gets very near to another real value, which I denoted $x_0$.

Comment: @user525966 my definition is correct. You are confused because you are used to looking at the asymptotics $x\to\infty$, where one obviously has to look at very large numbers, i.e. numbers larger than a certain bound. That was not my question. The Big O notation also makes sense when taking the limit to a real number.